# How do I add a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, material-design

So I made "white card" with HTML & CSS using Materialize. Here's how it looks right now: http://prntscr.com/ata21c My question is: How could I add there "horizontal" scroll bar, so if I add there more "cards" then I can just scroll horizontally to see all of those.

//EDIT
Alright I got the scroll wheel, but thing is no. They still "stack" down to each other :/ http://prntscr.com/atamlf

```
                                <div class="keystore-content">
                                <span class="keystore-title valign-wrapper">Key Store</span>
                                <br>
                                    <div class="container center"style="overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;display:inline-block">
                                        <div id="mainthing">
                                        <div id="case1" style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'> <div class='card item-card2 waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;width:220px' id=''> <div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>Sui Has No Swag</div> <img title="Key" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiejrL1Zi0aaRd25E6IXgktTYxKWtZOKHzztSuJ11ibqQoYqi3FDg80c4NnezetGrA31LSA/200fx200'></div></div>
                                        <div id="case2" style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'> <div class='card item-card2 waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;width:220px' id=''> <div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>Sui Has No Swag</div> <img title="Key" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiejrL1Zi0aaRd25E6IXgktTYxKWtZOKHzztSuJ11ibqQoYqi3FDg80c4NnezetGrA31LSA/200fx200'></div></div>
                                        <div id="case2" style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'> <div class='card item-card2 waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;width:220px' id=''> <div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>Sui Has No Swag</div> <img title="Key" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiejrL1Zi0aaRd25E6IXgktTYxKWtZOKHzztSuJ11ibqQoYqi3FDg80c4NnezetGrA31LSA/200fx200'></div></div>
                                        <div id="case2" style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'> <div class='card item-card2 waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;width:220px' id=''> <div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>Sui Has No Swag</div> <img title="Key" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiejrL1Zi0aaRd25E6IXgktTYxKWtZOKHzztSuJ11ibqQoYqi3FDg80c4NnezetGrA31LSA/200fx200'></div></div>
                                        <div id="case2" style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'> <div class='card item-card2 waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;width:220px' id=''> <div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>Sui Has No Swag</div> <img title="Key" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiejrL1Zi0aaRd25E6IXgktTYxKWtZOKHzztSuJ11ibqQoYqi3FDg80c4NnezetGrA31LSA/200fx200'></div></div>
                                        <div id="case2" style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'> <div class='card item-card2 waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;width:220px' id=''> <div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>Sui Has No Swag</div> <img title="Key" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiejrL1Zi0aaRd25E6IXgktTYxKWtZOKHzztSuJ11ibqQoYqi3FDg80c4NnezetGrA31LSA/200fx200'></div></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow-x` property specifies what to do when the content overflows at the left and right edges. Set it to *auto*. The `white-space` property specifies how to handle white-spaces inside the element. Set it to *nowrap* to supress line breaks.

```css
div {
 overflow-x: auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I am doing something wrong. I'll edit my first post.